# Will there be a better alternative than Uniy in future?

Tags: unity

I'm running Ubuntu for a long time and many of my students at our University switched from Windows to your great OS after my lessons.

But after that forced update to Unity you lost a lot of fans. Many students came and asked what they should do. We tried Gnome Shell (it's much better than Unity) but it could not nearly compare to Gnome 2.x!

If you go your way with Unity in future you will only help Microsoft and loose the leadership in Linux distros. Please give us Gnome 2.x back - as soon as possible!

Michael

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This sort of discussion is a better fit for the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org).

Answer (score -1):

It is quite simply not true that anyone has forced you to upgrade to Unity. You can still use the old shell if you don't like the new one, as these screenshots prove. Nobody has even forced you to upgrade Ubuntu, with 10.04 being supported for another full year after the next LTS is released in April. It is much better to ask questions.

Anyway, this is how my Ubuntu 11.10 desktop looked after spending two minutes customizing it. As you can see, it is the old desktop.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice. But you actually have not provided any info on how to move back from Unity.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs How to move back from unity wasn't the question asked. :)

Comment: His question was if there would be better shells in the future. He based his question on the false assumption that the old shell was no longer available. He also asked to get Gnome 2 back, but it is highly likely that he was only talking about the shell, and not about the rest of the desktop environment. I have proven that instead of taking Ubuntu back to Gnome 2, Gnome Panel have been brought forward to Gnome 3, which is used in 11.10. In other words, I did actually answer his question.